# Space in MySQL search

Tags: mysql, search

My query is formulated thus:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, id FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('".$query."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,10";
```

So searching for `tom` retrieves:

```
Tom Anderson   |   1
Tom Bennet     |   2
Tom Cane       |   3
```

However, if I search for `tom anderson` the query compiles to:

```
 ...MATCH (name) AGAINST ('tom anderson*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)...
```

Which returns the same set of results (I only want the first). How should I change my query?

Comment: I can't test right now, but `AGAINST ('"tom anderson*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` (note the quotes) should do it, as should `AGAINST ('+tom +anderson%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` (although that would also find "anderson tom").

Comment: I put the `*` outside the `"`.. Is that there a preference?

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Convert to an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use a `+` to indicate a word must be present, or use `"` to indicate a complete frase

Check the boolean [mode manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

I guess this'll work

```
 ...MATCH (name) AGAINST ('"tom anderson"*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)...
```